# Adding a new counter variable within a for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script

I am working on a project using google-apps-script. If a certain spreadsheet cell has a number, I want that row to be copied the number of times specified by a certain cell, for example, B2 has number 6. I've managed to copy the row 6 times, but I am trying to manipulate data, and seem to be not further able to manipulate data.

Following is the data I have:

```
Col1   Col2       Col3
Name   6          07/14/2019
```

Following is what I want:

```
Col1   Col2       Col3
Name   Count 1    07/14/2019
Name   Count 2    07/14/2019
Name   Count 3    07/14/2019
Name   Count 4    07/14/2019
Name   Count 5    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
```

Following is what I keep getting:

```
Col1   Col2       Col3
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
Name   Count 6    07/14/2019
```

This is the code so far:

```
function sample(data){

  var returnData = [];

  var col1 = data[0];
  var col2 = data[1];
  var col3 = new Date(data[2]);
  var count = 0;

  if (col2 > 1){
    var tempData = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < col2; i++){
      tempData[0] = col1;
      tempData[1] = "Count" + count;
      tempData[2] = col3;
      
      returnData.push(tempData);
    }
    count++;
  }
  return returnData;
};
```

The things I have tried, I have tried placing the count variable after the if statement, I have also tried to place the count variable inside the for loop, and I have also tried placing the count++ within the for loop and after the loop. But I keep ending with the last count but unable to implement the count. What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Try declaring var tempData = []; inside the for loop

Comment: Can you post the response so I can put it as solved? Moving the tempData[] and bringing up the count++ within the for loop actually solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring `var tempData = [];` inside the for loop.

Here is the code.

```js
// Add your code here
function sample(data){

  var returnData = [];

  var col1 = data[0];
  var col2 = data[1];
  var col3 = new Date(data[2]);

  if (col2 > 1){
    
    for(var i = 1; i <= col2; i++){
      var tempData = [];
      tempData[0] = col1;
      tempData[1] = "Count " + i;
      tempData[2] = col3;
      
      returnData.push(tempData); 
    }
  }
  return returnData; 
};

function test()
{
  var returnData = sample(['Name',6,'07/14/2019']);
  for(var i = 0; i < returnData.length; i++){
    console.log(returnData[i][0] + ' ' + returnData[i][1] + ' ' + returnData[i][2])
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: I can mark this as solved, this was really good since I was able to see the results right away. How did you allow "Run code snippet"?

Comment: When you want to add code, use the <> plugin to insert HTML, javascript code. If you use that, it gives the feature to run as well

Answer (score 0):

Moving `count++` inside for loop should solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Yow bro, if you already have `i` why do you need `count` for ?

```js
function sample(data){

  var returnData = [];

  var col1 = data[0];
  var col2 = data[1];
  var col3 = new Date(data[2]);
 

  if (col2 > 1){
    var tempData = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= col2; i++){
      tempData[0] = col1;
      tempData[1] = "Count" + i;
      tempData[2] = col3;
      
      returnData.push(tempData);
    }
  }
  return returnData;
};
```

Comment: Because i started at zero. This is an issue with google sheets I'm guessing. When getting data from the sheets it starts at 1, when using arrays it starts at zero, for now, I'm not trying to break the functionalities any more, I can try using i+1, but I don't know if I i will come across any issues, such as not reading the last row.

Comment: One thing is them sheets and another your looping as long as you don’t get a index out of range you’ll be all you, but if you want to do it like you have it, then all you need to do is move your count++ inside of your for loop, but if you wanna do it like that then a while is much better than a for loop

Comment: The issue wasn't with count++, it is where I placed the tempData[]. I was hoping Bharat would have answered the question, that was his comment, I've tried what he suggested, moved the tempData[] within the for loop, and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sample = ([col1, col2, col3] = []) => {
  let returnData = [];

  if (col2 > 0)
    for (var i = 1; i <= col2; i++) {
      returnData.push([col1, "Count " + i, col3]);
    }

  return returnData;
};
```

Comment: Maybe it is the right answer, but I am not comfortable with lamdas yet, so I can't even understand how the inner working is, lamdas are supposed to simplify things, it complicates things for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution so far was from Bharat, but he didn't post the answer so I will answer it. The solution to this issue was to move the tempData[] within the for loop and to keep the count++ within the for loop, after pushing the tempData.

```
function sample(data){

  var returnData = [];

  var col1 = data[0];
  var col2 = data[1];
  var col3 = new Date(data[2]);
  

  if (col2 > 1){
    var count = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < col2; i++){
      var tempData = [];

      tempData[0] = col1;
      tempData[1] = "Count" + count;
      tempData[2] = col3;
      
      returnData.push(tempData);
      count++;
    }
  }
  return returnData;
};
```